# In Android Studio, how do you switch a fragment to another fragment using java code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

On `activity_main` I have `btnToggle` and a `fragment_text`. 
[image]

I want to switch `fragment_text` to `fragment_image` when the user taps `btnToggle`.
[image]

```
private void btnToggle_OnClick() {
    //what goes here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add fragment dynamically and then replace like below:-

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SectionDescriptionFragment bdf = new SectionDescriptionFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.book_description_fragment, bdf);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: to add fragment dynamically can follow http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/

Comment: What is `SectionDescriptionFragment`?

Comment: Its example only. You can use your own name of fragment similar to example mentioned in link.